# Renaming and Inserting Array results into a different table

Tags: php, mysql

//First I'm assigning a $variable ($emailzipmatch) to query a database table called(repzipcodes) and having it pull and display 1 to 3 records based on matching up a customer's zip code (RepZipCode = $CustomerZipMatch) with 1 to 3 other people (GROUP BY RepId HAVING COUNT(1) <= 3") that want that customer's information from that particular zip code.

// CODE WORKS BELOW

```
$emailzipmatch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repzipcodes WHERE RepZipCode = $CustomerZipMatch GROUP BY RepId HAVING COUNT(1) <= 3") or die(mysql_error());

$recipients = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($emailzipmatch)) 
{ 
$recipients[] = $row['RepEmail'];

echo "Agent's Email Address: ";

echo 'font color="#FF7600"',$row['RepEmail'], '/font';

echo '<br />'; 

echo "Rep's ID: "; 
echo '<br />';
echo 'font color="#FF7600"',$row['RepId'], '/font';
echo '<br />';
echo 'hr align="left" width="50%" size="2" /';
}
```

//MY PROBLEM BELOW

// For the NEXT step of the process above I would take $row['RepEmail'] and $row['RepId'] which can have 1 to 3 results and assign the 1 to 3 results a new $variable so it can be inserted into a different db table so I can track the results of the query ($emailzipmatch = ) from the top of the page: ie..

```
<New Variable>   <Listed from above>
$SentRepId 0   = RepId (results from above echo area)
$SentRepId 1   = RepId (results from above echo area)
$SentRepId 2   = RepId (results from above echo area)
```

// Below I'd like to insert the above results into a new database

```
$?Variable??? = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentemail 
(SentRepId0, SentRepId1, SentRepId2,SentDateTime
) VALUES (
'$_SESSION[RepId]', // ?????
'$_SESSION[RepId]', // ?????
'$_SESSION[RepId]', // ?????
 NOW()
  )") or die(mysql_error());
```

//Thank ahead of time for any help you guys can give me. Please respond with ANY question if my coding or request isn't clear or if I've been confusing due to my lack of experience with PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are going for here. I have done something similar before where I needed to keep a record for a while so I gave each search result an id on output and placed them in separate rows of a table along with a time stamp so it could be cleaned up at a later time or if you wish to search by time (mysql has a timestamp of it's own also but that's another thing to look in to if you haven't already)

So to make a 'log table' for example you might want to design something that works like the following:

```
<?php

$search_id = md5(uniqid()).rand(100,999); //// MAKE AN ID FOR THE SEARCH;
$timestamp = time(); // IN CASE YOU WANT TO CLEAN UP AT A LATER DATE, MUST BE AN INTEGER IN MYSQL (so you can use a less than $timestamp in the delete query)

$emailzipmatch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repzipcodes WHERE RepZipCode = $CustomerZipMatch GROUP BY RepId HAVING COUNT(1) <= 3") or die(mysql_error()); // if you are just wanting to limit the results look at LIMIT in a mysql tutorial somewhere. 

$recipients = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($emailzipmatch)) 
{ 
//// THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE (and at the end of the while loop insert in to a table, in your case 'sentemail')

mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentemail (search_id, rep_email, rep_id, zip_code, timestamp) VALUES ('$search_id', '{$row['RepEmail']}', '{$row['RepId']}', $CustomerZipMatch, $timestamp);") or die(mysql_error()); // or what ever details you are after
}

?>
```

This should leave you with a reference table that you can search for by different criteria. Not the most perfect way of doing it but it will get the job done.

Hope that gives you a different perspective on it :)

In regards to "due to my lack of experience with PHP": As you develop your skills, and you will I'm sure, take some time to look at Object Oriented PHP in the future. For more server heavy or complicated things it can be worth knowing. I'm saying this to you now because I wish someone had told me earlier.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks to your solution I'm changing my process. I'm just using your "INSERT" part of the solution and it's creating a different record for each result, so I'm going to make it easy on myself and take out the ($SentRepId0 = RepId, $SentRepId1 = RepId, etc) to create only 1 record and just have it create a separate record for 1 to 3 results. I'm just tracking which Rep gets "x" amount of results. So, THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE SOLUTION!!!!

Comment: No worries :) Good luck with it all.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have user access, you can do:

```
$?Variable??? = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db1.sentemail (SentRepId0, SentRepId1,SentRepId2,SentDateTime) VALUES (
'$_SESSION[RepId]', // ?????
'$_SESSION[RepId]', // ?????
'$_SESSION[RepId]', NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
```